# How to replace a string with another string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Consider the following code:

```js
    var text2='ain';
    let text = "The rain in SPAIN stays mainly in the plain";
    let result = text.replaceAll(/text2/g,'__');
 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

The string `result` is the same as `text`. How do I fix this problem? I just want every `ain` in text string to get replaced with `___`.

Comment: [How do you use a variable in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-use-a-variable-in-a-regular-expression)

Comment: Just don't use a regex. `text.replaceAll(text2, '__');` should work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-do-i-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: @DamianChudobiński Yes, it does. Thank you. But I wanted to use regular expression, so I learned it.

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
<script>
    const text2 = 'ain';
    const text = "The rain in SPAIN stays mainly in the plain";

    // Create a regular expression using the 'text2' variable as a string
    const regex = new RegExp(text2, 'g');

    // Use the 'regex' variable in the 'replaceAll' method
    const result = text.replaceAll(regex, '___');

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
</script>
```

Comment: Don't use let and var like this, instead use const.

Answer (score 0):

Need to create a new regular expression using the **RegExp** constructor and pass the text2 variable and the *'g'* flag to make the replacement global, you can use the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
        const text2 = 'ain';
        const text = "The rain in SPAIN stays mainly in the plain";
        const regex = new RegExp(text2, 'g');
        const result = text.replaceAll(regex, '___');

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

If you want to replace the 'AIN' in capital letters too. That can be done by adding the 'i' flag to the regular expression, then it becomes case-insensitive.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    const text2 = 'ain';
    const text = "The rain in SPAIN stays mainly in the plain";
    const regex = new RegExp(text2, 'gi');
    const result = text.replaceAll(regex, '___');
 
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  let text2 = 'ain';
  let text = "The rain in SPAIN stays mainly in the plain";      
  let regex = new RegExp(text2, 'gi');
  let result = text.replace(regex, '---');    
  console.log(result); 
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```